# Product Export not displaying qty

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to export magento product on a csv file using Import/Export->Data-Profiles, The profile is running but for some reason the script does not include product qty, I have this on my function

```
function exportProduct($profileID){
    global $mageFile;
    require_once($mageFile.'app/Mage.php');
    Mage::init();
    $profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
    $profile->load($profileID);
    if (!$profile->getId()) {
    Mage::log('error: ' . $profileID . ' - incorrect profile id',null,'product_import.log');
        return;
    }
    Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
    $profile->run();

}
```

[image: data profile settings]

But after i run my profile qty column is empty. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you in advance.